# Для чего используется символ ` (обратная кавычка, backquote, backtick)?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

Для чего используют символы <kbd>`</kbd>?

Например:

```
python3.4 `which ptpython`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это несколько устаревшая форма записи для вызова вложенной оболочки.

уже в [posix version 2 (1997)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/) присутствует и [более удобная (и рекомендуемая стандартом posix) форма записи](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_006_003): `$(command)`.

удобство можно увидеть наглядно при вложении нескольких вызовов один внутрь другого:

```
$ echo `echo \`echo \\\`echo 1\\\` 2\` 3` 4
1 2 3 4
$ echo $(echo $(echo $(echo 1) 2) 3) 4
1 2 3 4
```

---

смысл использования: во время интерпретации команды оболочка, встретив конструкцию `$(command)` (или `` `command` ``), запускает новый процесс оболочки, в котором выполняется указанная команда, а всё, что возвратит команда в *stdout*, будет подставлено вместо этой конструкции (то, что команда возвратит в *stderr*, добавится к *stderr* основного процесса оболочки).

---

> Например: `` python3.4 `which ptpython` ``

в данном случае сначала будет выполнена команда `which ptpython`, которая вёрнет (в *stdout*) полный путь к программе `ptpython`. если, конечно, такая программа присутствует в вашей системе в каком-либо из каталогов, упомянутых в переменной окружения `$PATH`. если отсутствует — будет возвращена пустая строка.

затем результат (полный путь либо пустая строка) будет передана программе `python3.4` в качестве первого аргумента. если, конечно, такая программа присутствует в вашей системе в каком-либо из каталогов, упомянутых в переменной окружения `$PATH`. если отсутствует — вы получите сообщение об ошибке: *command not found*.

---

посмотреть текущее значение переменной окружения, например, `$PATH`, можно так:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 5):

Обратные кавычки используются в баше для записи какой-то выполнимой команды, результат работы которой будет использован в скрипте.

```
Например попробуйте: echo `whoami` и echo 'whoami'
```

Первый вариант выполнит команду whoami и распечатает ее результат (имя текущего пользователя), второй вариант просто распечатает строку "whoami".